# Stopping a process by sending SIGUSR1 and waking up by sending SIGUSR2

Tags: operating-system, ipc

How do I stop a process by sending SIGUSR1 and wake that up by sending SIGUSR2? Is it possible? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle this problem you could create the signal handler in the following way to stop and continue a process.

```
void signalHandler(int sig)   
{  
    if(sig==SIGUSR1)  
    {  
        // issue a wait mutex  
        kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);  
    }  
    else if(sig==SIGUSR2)  
    {  
        // issue a signal mutex
        kill(getpid(), SIGCONT);
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Unknown signal\n")  exit(1);          
    }
}
```